# Test if email is send in Meteor Velocity

Tags: testing, meteor, meteor-velocity

Is it possible to confirm emails are being sent in Meteor Velocity tests?

I thought I could just have a method in `tests` with the same name that override/duplicates the method, but that doesn't work. I tried this:

*In my regular code:*

```
Meteor.methods(
   email: (parameters) ->
      sendAnEmail(parameters)
)
```

*In `tests`:*

```
Meteor.methods(
   email: (parameters) ->
      differentBehaviorForTesting(parameters)
      # I could call some super() here if necessary
)
```

But this always gets me a

```
Error: A method named 'email' is already defined
```

Comment: I moved the question about overloading/overriding/extending Meteor methods into a [seperate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105601/can-i-override-extend-meteor-methods) since this use case was very specific and the answers suited it very well, but not the general question I originally intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create an email fixture that looks something like this:

```
  var _fakeInboxCollection = new Package['mongo'].Mongo.Collection('Emails');

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    _clearState();
    _initFakeInbox();
  });

  Meteor.methods({
    'clearState': _clearState,
    'getEmailsFromInboxStub': function () {
      return _fakeInboxCollection.find().fetch()
    }
  });

  function _initFakeInbox () {
    _fakeInboxCollection.remove({});
    Email.send = function (options) {
      _fakeInboxCollection.insert(options);
    };
  }

  function _clearState () {
    _fakeInboxCollection.remove({});
  }
```

This will allow you to send emails normally and also clear / fetch the emails using DDP.