# Can I override/extend Meteor methods?

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to somehow override a method in Meteor?
Or define another function such that *both* will get called?

*In my regular code:*

```
Meteor.methods(
   foo: (parameters) ->
      bar(parameters)
)
```

*Somewhere else that gets loaded later (e.g. in `tests`):*

```
Meteor.methods(
   # override
   foo: (parameters) ->
      differentBehavior(parameters)
      # I could call some super() here
)
```

So I would expect to either have both `bar` and `differentBehavior` executed or only `differentBehavior` and some possibility to call `super()`.

Does this exist?

Comment: I think it is possible to overwrite a method using this: Meteor.methods.foo = function () {}; If so, and assuming that there was a previous Meteor.methods.bar cb, then I would wrap with a function and call that bar() and then execute foo().

Comment: Anyway, I would choose a different way to go. This is clearly not correct IMHO.

Comment: Do you have a specific example of what method you would like to override? With JavaScript prototyping this may be possible. Some of the internal Meteor (maybe all, I have no idea I haven't checked), methods are prototypes can be overridden. I would be curious to try myself just for kicks.

Comment: This came into my mind [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080348/test-if-email-is-send-in-meteor-velocity?lq=1) but I now think that there are several scenarios where (at least) in testing it could be very beneficial to get a "copy" of the call.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by get a "copy" of the call? It seems your linked question answers it pretty well.

Comment: Well, if you have multiple `deny` functions for example all of them will get called. I imagined defining two functions and both getting called simultaneously with the same parameters - but now that I think of it, this wouldn't make sense if they returned something. The linked question shows great work arounds but doesn't answer the core question if it is somehow possible.

Answer (score 5):

To override a method, on server side you can do:

```
Meteor.methods({
   'method_name': function () {
       //old method definition
   }
});

Meteor.default_server.method_handlers['method_name'] = function (args) {
    //put your new code here
};
```

The `Meteor.default_server.method_handlers['method_name']` has to be included after the method definition.

To override a method (also know as a stub), on client side you can do:

```
Meteor.connection._methodHandlers['method_name'] = function (args) {
    //put your new code here
};
```

The `Meteor.connection._methodHandlers['method_name']` has to be included after the method definition.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways you can do what you are intending to do.

For instance, the simplest way to overwrite any function would be to do something like:

```
Meteor.publish = function() { /* My custom function code */ };
```

We just over-wrote the Meteor.publish with our own instance.

However, if you want to wrapper a function like a proxy (I believe this is called a "proxy pattern":

```
var oldPublish = Meteor.publish();
Meteor.publish = function() {
  oldPublish(arguments);   // Call old JS with arguments passed in
}
```

ES6 also added a `Proxy` object that allows you to do some similar things (read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)).

Also there are lots of [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) libraries ([CujoJS](https://github.com/cujojs/meld), [jQuery-AOP](https://github.com/gonzalocasas/jquery-aop), and [node-aop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-aop) to name a few) for JavaScript that allow you to do before, after, around pointcuts on functions/objects.  You could even roll-your-own if you wanted too.

Comment: Thanks for the general answer, but I was trying to ask for the [Meteor.methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods) thing - maybe I wasn't specific enough in my question (although the code sample covered that).

Comment: Well, since the `Meteor.methods` takes an object as a parameter so it is not plainly obvious how they are stored.  After poking around a bit on the server, it looks like the methods are stored in `Meteor.default_server.method_handlers` on the server-side, so one could either wrap the functions as described in the post above or simply overwrite them.  If you want to print them out, create a `Meteor.startup()` and put this in it:  `console.log('Meteor.methods(): ', Meteor.default_server.method_handlers);`.  That will print out the list of functions currently defined.